# Tell Sonar to ignore or recoginze preprocessor in java

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

When running sonar on my java project  ,the sonar run fails because of a preprocessor usage in java code. Below is the exception

```
  ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not execute Checkstyle
    Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Exception was thrown while processing SomeClass.java
```

It appears that in the java file , sonar failed to identify or ignore the pre-processor conditions

```
#if SOMEVAR!="abc"

#endif
```

Is there any way to tell sonar to ignore or identify the preprocessors in java code.  I want sonar to continue with the scan.

Comment: Sonar is for scanning Java source code. Java source code can't contain preprocessor conditions. Or put differently: if your source file contains preprocessor statements, then it isn't Java source code. Using preprocessors is exceedingly rare in the Java world, so you'll be hard-pressed to find many tools that support it (and most tools that handle Java source code won't consider it a bug if they don't support it).

Comment: Thanks for Reply @JoachimSauer. My situation is that we have single code base which supports on-prem VM and Cloud and different libraries and method signatures as part of it.  The code has Pre-processors based IF/ELSE  like  #if profile=VM  else if profile=CLOUD.  i can't remove the pre-processors as the build fails because we have single code base/class for both the logics (VM and cloud).  Is there any solution ?  Does it mean sonar doesn't support pre-processors ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure Sonar doesn't support pre-processors. The usual way to solve your kind of problem in the Java world is to design some interfaces that have different implementations based on the target platform/capability. This would mean that your entire build could be "real Java" and has the added benefit that switching/picking the profile at runtime becomes possible (as opposed to having to recompile to target a different profile).

Comment: For those who ran into same issue as me : - Fortunately , i had only 2 java files which has pre-processors in my entire project. So as a workaround , i just excluded those 2 files form scan using sonar.exlclusions='**/Test.java','**/Test2.java' and the scan went fine. 
However , i admit that whatever way @JoachimSauer suggested is good approach in longer run.